# Read separately the elements of a string in php

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to import a csv file into a database, but I'm getting stuck on getting separately the elements of the string returned while reading the file.

I read the csv file like this:

```
if(!file_exists($fileURL) || !is_readable($fileURL)){
    return FALSE;
}

$header = null;
$data = array();

if (($handle = fopen($fileURL, 'r')) !== FALSE)
{
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
    {

        if($header === null){
            $header = $row;
        }
        else{
            $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
}

return $data;
```

Then that returns an array like this:

```
array(1) { ["codeA  codeB   codeC   codeD   codeE   codeF   codeG   codeH   codeI   codeJ   codeK   codeL   codeM   codeN   codeO   codeP   codeQ   codeR   codeS   codeT   codeU"]=> string(293) "6928549666338    6928549666338 6928549666338 6928549666338   6928549666338   6928549666338   6928549666338   6928549666338   6928549666338   6928549666338   6928549666338   6928549666338   6928549666338   6928549666338 6928549666338 6928549666338   6928549666338   6928549666338   6928549666338   6928549666338   6928549666338" }
```

When I try to separate the values, it won't happen and I don't understand why!

I try to separate them like this:

```
$separatedArray = array();

$keys = array_keys($arrayToSeparate);
$separatedKeys = explode(" ",$keys[0]);

$values = array_values($arrayToSeparate);
$separatedValues = explode(" ",$values[0]);



foreach($separatedKeys as $i)
{
    $key = $separatedKeys[$i];
    $separatedArray[$key] = $separatedValues[$i];
}

    return $separatedArray;
```

I've tried with str_getcsv, str_replace and nothing works.. 
I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: What is the structure of the CSV?

Comment: There are multiple spaces in the first value of your array. And in your `explode()` function there is just one.

Comment: Do you need the keys? Because in your array there is only one... So should the keys be 0, 1, 2, ... or codeA, codeb, ... ?

Comment: @tastro I do need the keys, I use them to create the SQL query. That's exactly what I pretend to do in the last piece of code. First I separate all the key values and store them separately, then I do the same with the Values array and after that I make an associative array with the keys storing the values, and as both have the same length I only need to iterate over them one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
$separatedKeys = explode(" ",$keys[0]);
```

to this:

```
$separatedKeys = explode(" ",preg_replace("@[\s]+@i", ' ', $keys[0]));
```

Do the same for the values array. Don't know why you have 2 anyways... As they both do the same.

**UPDATE:**

```
$separatedArray = explode(" ",preg_replace("@[\s]+@i", ' ', $arrayToSeparate[0]));
return $separatedArray;
```

**UPDATE 2 (by using/changing your code):**

```
$separatedArray = array();

$separatedValues = explode(" ", preg_replace("@[\s]+@i", ' ', $arrayToSeparate[0]));

for ($i = 0; $i < count($separatedValues); $i++) {
    $separatedArray[$i] = $separatedValues[$i];
}

return $separatedArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

try preg_match_all on \w+

i.e preg_match_all('/\w+/',$keys[0],$keys);

same for values.. your resultant array will be in keys...

Still dont understand why you are using two seperate sets, but it could be your requirement